# How can I properly fetch FirebaseFirestore data (image file) of specific user in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, storage

I am getting a RenderFlex error when I attempt to fetch data from Firestore.

I'd say the image file was successfully fetched, but instead of the image to display, only the url is shown and this seems to cause the RenderFlex overflow issue.

On the debug console, this was the error that was thrown.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>#005ce):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
lib\…\courses\course_grid.dart:30
```

This is my code

```
class CourseGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final subjects = Provider.of<SubjectsProvider>(context).subjects;
    final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      FutureBuilder(
                          future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('user')
                              .doc(userId).get(),
                          builder: (BuildContext ctx,
                              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> futureSnapshot) {
                            Map<String, dynamic> data = futureSnapshot.data?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                            return Text('${data['profile-picture']}');
                          })
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 400,[enter image description here][1]
            child: GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              itemCount: subjects.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                value: subjects[index],
                child: CourseItem(),
              ),
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 1,
                childAspectRatio: 7 / 6,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I followed this guide on the official docs and expected the data to be fetched and rendered successfully, but I am getting the error as shown on the screenshot below.
What can I do to fix, please?

I am using;

Flutter version 2.10.4 channel stable
Dart 2.16.2
firebase_auth: ^3.3.12
firebase_storage: ^10.2.11
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.11

Comment: futureSnapshot.data?.data() is returning null value, check if data exits in firestore.

Comment: Data does exist in Firestore. I double-checked before posting.

Comment: you need to debug why the data is coming null, try logging userId value once.

Comment: How can I do this, please?